# Can I use an external touchscreen with the Nexus 4?

Tags: nexus-4, touchscreen, external-display

I've seen a few videos of folk connecting their Nexus to an external monitor with a SlimPort HDMI cable. Would a 10 or 7 inch touchscreen work the same way? Or would it need a different cable connection?

If this is possible I can extend my Nexus 4 to a tablet :)

Comment: Are you asking if the "touch" portion will be functional?

Comment: Yes, the video I'm sure it will.

Comment: Duplicate confirmed.